# Only one POST action, "Multiple actions were found that match the request" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, generics, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that inherits from a generic base controller, both have a POST action, where the base controller's action is generic. A domain entity is set as the type parameter of the generic base controller and some actions can get a view model type parameter passed (like the POST and PUT) for the generic methods of the generic base controller.

This generic base controller inherits from a regular base controller, on which a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` executes a method on to set the `Entity Framework`'s `DbContext` instance. I don't know if the latter is relevant, when I removed this the problem remained.

I have one route Web API defined:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now, when I try to call the POST action on every controller that inherits from the generic base controller, I get the error mentioned in the title. The thing is, with other HTTP methods no error occur (for instance the PUT) and when I change the name of the POST action on the generic base controller to 'Add', for instance, the error remains.

This is the controller I call (just the relevant parts):

```
public class TablesController : GenericBaseController<Table>
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(TablePostModel tableModel)
    {
        return base.Add(tableModel);
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Put(TablePostModel tableModel)
    {
        return base.Put(tableModel);
    }
}
```

The generic base controller's actions:

```
protected HttpResponseMessage Post<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel)
        where TViewModel : BaseModel, new()
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                string.Format("The view model {0} cannot be null", typeof(TViewModel)));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TEntity entity = Mapper<TViewModel, TEntity>.Map(viewModel);

            try
            {
                entity = Uow.GetRepository<TEntity>().Add(entity);
                Uow.Commit();
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                MvcValidationExtension.AddModelErrors(this.ModelState, ex);
                return BadRequestResponse();
            }

            return OkResponse(entity);
        }

        return BadRequestResponse();

    }

protected HttpResponseMessage Put<TViewModel>(TViewModel viewModel)
        where TViewModel : BaseModel, new()
    {
        if (viewModel == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(
                string.Format("The view model {0} cannot be null", typeof(TViewModel)));

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TEntity entity = Uow.GetRepository<TEntity>().GetById(viewModel.RowId);
            entity = ValueMapper<TViewModel, TEntity>.Map(viewModel, entity);

            try
            {
                entity = Uow.GetRepository<TEntity>().Update(entity);
                Uow.Commit();
            }
            catch (ValidationException ex)
            {
                MvcValidationExtension.AddModelErrors(this.ModelState, ex);
                return BadRequestResponse();
            }

            return OkResponse(entity);
        }

        return BadRequestResponse();
    }
```

Does anyone have a clue what this could be?

**EDIT**

Apparently, a public method in the base controller was the problem.

This was the method in question:

```
public void InitializeUnitOfWork(string connectionName = "")
```

Somehow this is seen as an `HttpPost` and collided with my earlier mentioned POST action on the tables controller. I still can't understand how this method (with a `string` as param) can be seen as being similar as the method on my tables controller.
Solution was to mark it as `internal` (so it doesn't get exposed via the API).

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I came across this error some time ago: try to change one of your methods' name (I know you tried that), but also add [HttpPost, ActionName("Post")] above both of them.

Comment: @erem I can't seem to set that attribute on the generic controller.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You literally saved my day. I faced exactly the same problem and It was not obvious behaviour